# PDO database for arabic characters

Tags: php, database, pdo, phpmyadmin, arabic

I want to insert Arabic characters to database using pdo with php, but I got these characters in database

```
&#1575;&#1604;&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593; &#1575
```

and when I use

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

the result was

```
   ??????????
```

I make the collection of the columns in phpMyadmin

```
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and this

```
utf_unicode_ci
```

but I still have the same error.

And I tried to make the connection like this: *(totti,totti is not my really username and password)*

```
parent::__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ams-competation;charset=utf8"', 'totti', 'totti');
```

but still I get the same error

And I also tried like this:

```
parent::__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ams-competation;charset=utf8', 'totti', 'totti'
                ,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

and doesn't work :(

and after submitting the form and before inserting to database i echo the values and i got arabic characters , that means my problems is in database , **but echo works just without using meta**

and when i tried to insert arabic characters from phpmyadmin IT WORKS

i am using

```
phpmyadmin in XAMPP 1.7.4
php 5.5.3
```

***finally i found the solution and it is:***

1. make the collection of the columns utf8_unicode_ci
2. put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the header

Comment: Try utf8_general_ci on the row

Comment: @eric.itzhak i tried it and still the same error

Comment: Changing the collation will not do anything useful, because as Michael Borgwaldt said, that is not where the problem is. The data is already coming into your database in this format from PHP. Are you typing these characters in some kind of a rich text editor (e.g. CKEditor)? Those like to convert plain characters into entities like this.

Comment: @DCoder i write my data into <input type='text' />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the connection to utf-8 when making connection to the database.

- If you're following rules and best practices:

Set the constants first in your config file like this:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'your_hostname');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'your_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_password');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'your_dbname');
define('PDO_DSN', 'mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET);
```

Then set your connection like this:

```
$_dbhandler = new PDO(PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"));
```

- Quick and dirty

Set your connection like this:

```
$dbhandler = new PDO('mysql:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_dbname;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely not in how you access the database. The characters you see are HTML encoded, so it looks like you're using something like `htmlentities()` on your data before writing it to the DB.

Comment: no i never used this statement , and i never heard about it :)

Answer (score 1):

> `define('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');` not working

use `define('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF8');` instead